# Get specific files vía SFTP by Regex - Bash Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sftp

I need to transfer some files from server **A** to server **B**.

The files located in server **A** that have to be transfered must acomplish with the following regular expression on their name:

> **`'^\(Name_\)\?[A-Z0-9]\{12,13\}[0-9]\{6\}\(BN\|CT\|PL\|XC\|XF\).zip$'`**

Is there a way to apply a sftp command that help me only to transfer those files?

I have tried to execute the get command using grep, but it doesnt work.

*Note: The process to be developed is located on server **B**.*

Regards

Comment: FYI -- safer to use `[[:upper:][:digit:]]` rather than `[A-Z0-9]` -- some locales have a collation order of `AaBbCc`, so you can get lowercase characters matched by `A-Z`.

Comment: As for your actual question, I'm quite certain you could do this with `lftp` (which, yes, **does** support behaving as a sftp client) with the `mirror:include-regex` configuration option. Don't have the time to work out the details right now myself, though.

Comment: sftp has a batch mode if you can use it. Use your expression to write the batch of commands to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with this regex and execute `scp` from serverA:

```
find . -regex '^\(Name_\)\?[A-Z0-9]\{12,13\}[0-9]\{6\}\(BN\|CT\|PL\|XC\|XF\).zip$' -exec \
scp '{}' auser@ahost:/path/on/destination \;
```

Comment: It must be a sftp Transfer necessarily.

Comment: to be able to sftp/scp from serverA to serverB, you do need to have required access on serverA.

Comment: `sftp`  and `scp` use same `ssh` for data transfer and authentication. `scp` can be used pretty much anywhere you are using `sftp`.

Comment: That depends. One can very much enable only sftp subsystem access without shell access -- as someone who wears a security hat, I've done that more than a few times.

Comment: (For that matter, one can build a custom SFTP server that implements the SFTP subsystem but not the exec interface -- see http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.3/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_server.SFTPServer for one example of how to get there; I've done that before when tasked with building a server that would expose to customers only the documentation/content to which their various purchases entitled them.)